# Why does a function recognize a const declared in another function?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and in the JS code below, the `const newTodo` is used in `handlTodoSubmit()` and I'm using it as an argument of `paintTodo()`.

what I know is: when I'm using a `var` in specific function, that `var` can only use in the function which it contained. but the `paintTodo()` is using `newToDo` value in `span.innerText`

How can this happen?

```js
const toDoForm = document.getElementById("toDoForm");
const toDoInput = document.getElementById("toDoInput");
const toDoList = document.getElementById("toDoList");

function paintTodo(list){
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = list;
    li.appendChild(span);
    toDoList.appendChild(li);
}

function handleTodoSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const newToDo = toDoInput.value;
    toDoInput.value = "";
    paintTodo(newToDo);
}

toDoForm.addEventListener("submit", handleTodoSubmit);
```

```html
<form id="toDoForm">
  <input type="text" id="toDoInput" />
  <input type="submit" />
  <ul id="toDoList"></ul>
</form>
```

Comment: `newToDo` is not used in `paintTodo`. You’re passing a function argument. You may want to go through a [tutorial](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Functions#function_parameters) again. See [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](/q/518000/4642212).

Comment: Scope is something related to **variables**, not actual objects... a single object can be bound to any number of variables with different scopes.

Comment: I updated the code to be a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your `const newToDo` is declared in `handleTodoSubmit` and only used in that context. As you can see, there is no call to `newToDo` in `paintTodo`.

Nontheless, the entity represented by `newToDo` and the one represented by `list` contain the same value (even though they are not the same)! In programming languages (a good number of them anyway), if you pass a variable or a constant to a function, that said function will copy it and use that copy (as in "I send you an e-mail with the PDF attached", you will only have a copy of my PDF).

The `newToDo` variable stays in `handleTodoSubmit`, but there exists a copy of it called `list` in `paintTodo`.

Comment: Additionnal half-unrelated explanation: if the variable passed to the function is an array or an object, a reference to that object will be copied, as in "Here is the link the the Google Docs document"; the link is copied, but the real document accessed by both our links is the same and can therefore be edited by one of us for both our versions.

Comment: now I understand the concept, thank u for ur kind explanation.